# Verb Tenses - Past vs. Present

Tags: verbs, present-tense

I have to write a paper in present tense, but I have few words I do not know how to change from past tense to present.

During the Holocaust Jews and other races **faced** torture and prosecution and were **forced** to live in concentration camps.

Could someone tell me how to convert the two bolded words?

Comment: _Face_ is a regular verb whose past tense (and  past participle) is _faced_. _Force_ is a regular verb whose past participle (and past tense) is _forced_.

Comment: Just FYI: in your sentence, **forced** is not a tensed verb; it is a past participle. The tensed verb is **were**.

Comment: You probably meant to say [persecution](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/persecution), not [prosecution](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/prosecution).